# How to pass async data to child component from parent component?

Tags: angularjs

I have a parent component

```
angular.module('app')
  .component('parentComponent', {
    template: `
          <child-component data="myData"></child-component>
    `,
```

I'm getting `myData` by asynchronous call

```
myMethod(params).then(data => {
    $ctrl.data = data;
});
```

and then I pass it down to my child component where I want modify it and display it in the template

```
angular.module('app')
.component('childComponent', {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: '',
    bindings: {
        data: '='
    },

    controller: function () {
    const $ctrl = this;

    $ctrl.$onInit = function () {
        console.log($ctrl.data);
    }
});
```

Problem is that data gets passed in before it is received and because of it it is undefined in the child component.

I'm not sure how do I wait for the data before passing it down.

Comment: `<child-component ng-if="data" ...>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `$onChanges` [Life-Cycle Hook](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks)

```
app.component('childComponent', {
    templateUrl: '',
    bindings: {
        data: '<'
    },    
    controller: function () {
        const $ctrl = this;        
        $ctrl.$onChanges = function (changes) {
            changes.data && console.log(changes.data.currentValue);
        };
    }
});
```

From the Docs:

> ## Life-cycle hooks
>
> Directive controllers can provide the following methods that are called by AngularJS at points in the life-cycle of the directive:
>
> - `$onChanges(changesObj)` - Called whenever one-way (`<`) or interpolation (`@`) bindings are updated. The `changesObj` is a hash whose keys are the names of the bound properties that have changed, and the values are an object of the form `{ currentValue, previousValue, isFirstChange() }`. Use this hook to trigger updates within a component such as cloning the bound value to prevent accidental mutation of the outer value. Note that this will also be called when your bindings are initialized.
>
> [— AngularJS Comprehensive API Reference - Life-Cycle Hooks](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks)