# How to invoke a function inside a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

### Calling a variable from another module

I got a player that displays the currently or latest played song. Now in order to keep the content updated. I used `$interval` and `$scope.$watch` to register the playing song, which displays in the developer console.

Now everytime a change in the songname is detected **I want to fire** the `variable "link"` which fires **the `load()` function** (this is essentially the one that needs to fire). However, the varbiale is in a different module.
How do I call it?

I'm not familiar enough with AngularJS to really edit the code, but I managed to get updated song info, alang with an if-statement so it only fires when a change is detected between the two funtions `CurrentSong` and `LatestSong`

```
angular.module('app', ['lastfm-nowplaying'])
    .controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$interval', function ($scope, $http, $interval) {

        $scope.lastFmConfig = {
            apiKey: 'API',
            user: 'USER',
            containerClass: 'content'
        };

        $scope.$watch('currentsongs', function (CurrentSong, LatestSong) {
            if (CurrentSong != LatestSong) {
                console.log("Change detected");
                console.log($scope.songdata);
            }

        }, true);
        var checkData = function (songcheck) {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'https://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getrecenttracks&user=USER&api_key=API&format=json&limit=1'
            }).then(function (songdata) {
                $scope.songdata = songdata;
                $scope.currentsongs = songdata.data.recenttracks.track[0].name;
                console.log($scope.currentsongs);
            }, function (error) {
                //oopsie
            });
        };
        checkData();
        $interval(function () {
            checkData();
        }, 10000);


  }]);
```

```
angular.module('lastfm-nowplaying', [])
    .directive('lastfmnowplaying', ['uiCreation', 'lastFmAPI', 'lastFmParser', function (uiCreation, lastFmAPI, lastFmParser) {
        var link = function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('config', function (value) {
                load();
            });

            var load = function () {....
```

Comment: You should share an object through a service for that kind of operations.

Comment: @briosheje could you give me an example on how to fix it, please?

Comment: It appears that the `load` function is in a directive in the other module. There are several approaches to invoking functions inside directives. One approach is to use [one-way binding (`'<'`)](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture) and the [`$onChanges` Life-Cycle Hook](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks).

Comment: @georgeawg Thanks once again for your comment. Can you create a fiddle for me, please? :) I keep getting stuck and my knowledge of angularjs is minimal

Comment: See [How to pass async data to child component from parent component?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51711426/5535245).

Comment: @georgeawg I really appriciate the help from you! I'm still having difficulty implementing your suggested answer. Could you edit it in the code I provided? If it's not too much to ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out!
Just by trail and error I managed to solve the issue.

The solution is actually pretty simple, as I knew I was close.

```
$scope.lastFmConfig = {
            apiKey: 'API',
            user: 'USER',
            containerClass: 'content'
        };

        $scope.$watch('currentsongs', function (CurrentSong, LatestSong) {
            if (CurrentSong != LatestSong) {
                console.log("Change detected");
                console.log($scope.songdata);
                $scope.lastFmConfig = {
            apiKey: 'API',
            user: 'USER',
            containerClass: 'content'
        };
            }
```

I simply ran the lastFmConfig again as soon as a change is detected.

Hope it may ever help someone out.